# Manipulate characters with sed

Tags: sed

I have a list of usernames and i would like add possible combinations to it.

Example.  Lets say this is the list I have

```
johna
maryb
charlesc
```

Is there is a way to use sed to edit it the way it looks like

```
ajohn
bmary
ccharles
```

And also

```
john_a
mary_b
charles_c
```

etc...

Can anyone assist me into getting the commands to do so,  any explanation will be awesome as well. I would like to understand how it works if possible.  I usually get confused when I see things like `'s/\.(.*....` without knowing what some of those mean... anyway thanks in advance.

EDIT ... I change the username

Comment: For understanding commands you find online you should just read a tutorial like [this one](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed s/\(user\)\(.\)/\2\1/`

Breakdown:

`sed s/string/replacement/` will replace all instances of `string` with `replacement`.

Then, `string` in that sed expression is `\(user\)\(.\)`. This can be broken down into two 
parts: `\(user\)` and `\(.\)`. Each of these is a **capture group** - bracketed by `\(` `\)`. That means that once we've matched something with them, we can reuse it in the replacement string.

`\(user\)` matches, surprisingly enough, the `user` part of the string. `\(.\)` matches any single character - that's what the `.` means. Then, you have two captured groups - `user` and `a` (or `b` or `c`).

The replacement part just uses these to recreate the pattern a little differently. `\2\1` says "print the second capture group, then the first capture group". Which in this case, will print out `auser` - since we matched `user` and `a` with each group.

ex:

```
$ echo "usera
> userb
> userc" | sed "s/\(user\)\(.\)/\2\1/"
auser
buser
cuser
```

You can change the `\2\1` to use any string you want - ie. `\2_\1` will give a_user, b_user, c_user.

Also, in order to match any preceding string (not just "user"), just replace the `\(user\)` with `\(.*\)`. Ex:

```
$ echo "marya
> johnb
> alfredc" | sed "s/\(.*\)\(.\)/\2\1/"
amary
bjohn
calfred
```

Comment: Hi Commander, thanks for your reply.  I made some edits to point to my needs more specific.  My apologies because i wasnt clear at the beginning.

Comment: +1, but, in your explanation, I suggest saying calling the 1st `s` argument _regex_ (or some such thing) rather than _string_; also, there is no need for the `g` option.

Comment: @user3635042: Simply replacing `user` with `.*` in the `sed` command will do what you want.

Comment: No, I guess there isn't, hey? I have a bad habit of just typing the g any time I want to match more than one pattern... ;) And like @mklement0 says, it's trivial to make this match other strings than user - editing.

Comment: @mklement0 that solved it.  Thank you very much  :D  
Commander, thanks

Answer (score 0):

here's a partial answer to what is probably the easy part.  To use sed to change usera to user_a you could use:

```
sed 's/user/user_/' temp
```

where temp is the name of the file that contains your initial list of usernames.  How this works:  It is finding the first instance of "user" on each line and replacing it with "user_"

Similarly for your dot example:

```
sed 's/user/user./' temp
```

will replace the first instance of "user" on each line with "user."

Comment: Thanks dlahr.  For the purpose of all the users have the same name pattern this will work fine.  Well, maybe i didnt asked it right, my fault... but what if instead of usera userb, would be johnc marym  etc

Answer (score 0):

`Sed` does not offer non-greedy regex, so I suggest `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/(.*?)(.)$/$2$1/g' file
ajohn
bmary
ccharles

perl -pe 's/(.*?)(.)$/$1_$2/g' file
john_a
mary_b
charles_c
```

That way you don't need to know the username before hand.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using `awk`

```
awk '{a=$NF;$NF="";$0=a$0}1' FS="" OFS="" file
ajohn
bmary
ccharles
```

and

```
awk '{a=$NF;$NF="";$0=$0"_" a}1' FS="" OFS="" file
john_a
mary_b
charles_c
```

By setting `FS` to nothing, every letter is a field in `awk`. You can then easy manipulate it.
And no need to using capturing groups etc, just plain field swapping.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^([^_]*)_?(.)$/\2\1/' file
```

This matches any charactes other than underscores (in the first back reference (\1)), a possible underscore and the last character (in the second back reference (\2)) and swaps them around.